# How to get the progress bar (with stages and tasks) with yarn-cluster master?

Tags: apache-spark, jar, progress-bar, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

When running a Spark Shell query using something like this:

```
spark-shell yarn --name myQuery -i ./my-query.scala
```

Inside my query is simple Spark SQL query where I read parquet files and run simple queries and write out parquet files. When running these queries I get a nice progress bar like this:

```
[Stage7:===========>                              (14174 + 5) / 62500]
```

When I create a jar using the exact same query and run it with the following command-line:

```
spark-submit \
  --master yarn-cluster \
  --driver-memory 16G \
  --queue default \
  --num-executors 5 \
  --executor-cores 4 \
  --executor-memory 32G \
  --name MyQuery \
  --class com.data.MyQuery \
  target/uber-my-query-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I don't get any such progress bar. The command simply says repeatedly

```
17/10/20 17:52:25 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1507058523816_0443 (state: RUNNING)
```

The query works fine and the results are fine. But I just need to have feedback when the process will finish. I have tried the following.

1. The web page of RUNNING Hadoop Applications does have a progress bar but it basically never moves. Even in the case of the spark-shell query that progress bar is useless.
2. I have tried get the progress bar through the YARN logs but they are not aggregated until the job is complete. Even then there is no progress bar in the logs.

Is there is a way to launch a spark query in jar on a cluster and have a progressbar?

Comment: Latest commit in `SparkSubmit.scala` says : " [SPARK-21568][CORE] ConsoleProgressBar should only be enabled in shells". Use Spark UI to monitor your job's progress.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When I create a jar using the exact same query and run it with the following command-line (...) I don't get any such progress bar.

The difference between these two seemingly similar Spark executions is the master URL.

In the former Spark execution with `spark-shell yarn`, the master is YARN in **client** deploy mode, i.e. the driver runs on the machine where you start `spark-shell` from.

In the latter Spark execution with `spark-submit --master yarn-cluster`, the master is YARN in **cluster** deploy mode (which is actually equivalent to `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster`), i.e. the driver runs on a YARN node.

With that said, you won't get the nice progress bar (which is actually called [ConsoleProgressBar](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/ConsoleProgressBar.scala)) on the local machine but on the machine where the driver runs.

A simple solution is to replace `yarn-cluster` with `yarn`.

---

**ConsoleProgressBar** shows the progress of active stages to standard error, i.e. `stderr`.

The progress includes the stage id, the number of completed, active, and total tasks.

ConsoleProgressBar is created when **spark.ui.showConsoleProgress** Spark property is turned on and the logging level of **org.apache.spark.SparkContext** logger is `WARN` or higher (i.e. less messages are printed out and so there is a "space" for ConsoleProgressBar).

You can find more information in Mastering Apache Spark 2's [ConsoleProgressBar](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sparkcontext-ConsoleProgressBar.html).

Comment: Thanks. My work around was to have a portable scala code that runs as `spark-shell` script and also compiles to a jar for `spark-submit`. So, I can have the progress bar while developing. That kinda works but is far from ideal. This is exactly what I needed.